# Find the number of $x$ digit numbers in base $n$

Tags: number-systems

I tried to understand this but I can't. It is confusing and I even don't know what the question mean. Help me out, Thanks!

> The number of $x$-digit numbers in base $n$ is
>   (a) $n^x$ (b) $n^x-1$ (c) $n^x-n$ (d) $n^x-n^{x-1}$

Comment: Well, for clarity, let $n=10$ and let $x=2$.  Then you are asking how many $2$ digit numbers there are in base $10$.

Comment: Is $00035$ a 5-digit base 10 number?

Comment: May be, I honestly don't know.

Comment: We really can't interpret your question for you.  The most common thing is to say, in base $10$, that the $2$ digit numbers are those integers between $10$ and $99$, inclusive.  So, for example, $05$ is not a $2$ digit number.

Comment: So, should I do a trail and error method? How can I know The answer from given options

Comment: Try some examples!  How many $2$ digits are there in base $10$?

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have some $x$-digit number. If we are free to choose any digits, there will be exactly $n^x$ numbers that you can express with these digits, but the numbers will not be unique as numbers, since $012 = 12$. So it we want to count all the numbers we can make with $x$ digits, we would need to disregard all the options where the leading number is $0$. But this leaves us with $n^{x-1}$ choices to remove!

So the answer is (d).

Comment: Now I can see why we require n^(x-1), I did'nt thought of that earlier. Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)